# Is it possible to make a Solr query span several documents grouped by a common field value?

Tags: solr

Is it possible to do a search across several documents in a Solr index that share a common field value and have Solr treat that as one document?

Let's say for example I upload each chapter of a book into Solr as a separate document, but they share a common field, `book` which is the title of the book.

```
<doc>
  <field name="id">book1_chap01</field>
  <field name="book">book1</field>
  <field name="text">The proof is in the pudding.</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">book1_chap02</field>
  <field name="book">book1</field>
  <field name="text">The concept is different than the reality.</field>
</doc>
```

If you search now for `proof AND concept` it would return nothing, because the words occur in separate documents.

I would like a search like `proof AND concept` to be performed over all documents that share the common book value "book1" as if they were one document.

Is such a thing possible in Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [Join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) operation that is available with Solr 4.0 might be able to help with this.

The following query works for the above:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr4b/collection1/select?q={!join%20from=title%20to=title}text:proof%20AND%20pudding
```

Comment: Could you perhaps substantiate this with an example?

Comment: Never mind, just tried it myself, and it seems to work. As a test, I added a document with "book2" and the word "proof" in it. The following query picks up only the ones with both terms as specified: http://localhost:8080/solr4b/collection1/select?q={!join%20from=title%20to=title}text:proof%20AND%20pudding

Answer (score 0):

You can filter results of book1 and then call OR query.This will be equivalent to what you are looking for.Query should be look like :

```
q=proof OR concept&fq=book:book1
```

Comment: Mmm, are you sure it is equivalent? The AND would ensure that a result is returned only if both terms are found in the virtual book1 document. With OR, surely, it will return them even if one of the terms is not present in virtual book1.

Comment: I know the difference between AND and OR :).I just misunderstood your need. I thought you want to find the result if it is in the book.

Comment: But he wants to find results if they are in a book! Your suggestion would've worked if the whole book was in a single document.